# The string can not be recognized as a valid DateTime value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to Create/Update data in Kendo UI Grid using Web Api connected to a SQL database.

Here is my Usuarios Class

```
public class UsuariosModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }        
    public String Usuario_Nombre { get; set; }        
    public String Password { get; set; }
    public String Nombre { get; set; }
    public String Apellido { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha_Creacion { get; set; }        
    public String Telefono { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
```

}

Create Usuarios

```
public void Guardar(String Nombre, String Apellido, String Usuario_Nombre, String Password, DateTime Fecha_Creacion, String Telefono, String Email)
    {
        try
        {
            DataBaseManager cn = new DataBaseManager();
            cn.Ejecutar("INSERT INTO USUARIOS(USU_NOMBRE, USU_APELLIDO, USU_NOMBRE_USUARIO, USU_PASSWORD, USU_FECHA_CREACION, USU_TELEFONO, USU_EMAIL) VALUES('" + Nombre + "','" + Apellido + "','" + Usuario_Nombre + "','" + Password + "','" + Fecha_Creacion + "','" + Telefono + "','" + Email + "')");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public void Guardar([FromBody] JObject data)
{
        String Nombre = data["Nombre"].ToString();
        String Apellido = data["Apellido"].ToString();
        String Usuario_Nombre = data["Usuario_Nombre"].ToString();
        String Password = data["Password"].ToString();
        DateTime Fecha_Creacion = Convert.ToDateTime(data["Fecha_Creacion"].ToString());
        String Telefono = data["Telefono"].ToString();
        String Email = data["Email"].ToString();            
        new UsuariosModel().Guardar(Nombre, Apellido, Usuario_Nombre, Password, Fecha_Creacion, Telefono, Email);
}
```

And Grid schema in JavaScript

```
model: {
                id: 'Codigo',
                fields: {
                    Codigo: { nullable: false, editable: false, format: '{0:n0}', type: 'number' },
                    Nombre: { nullable: false, editable: true, type: 'string' },
                    Apellido: { nullable: false, editable: true, type: 'string' },  
                    Usuario_Nombre: { nullable: false, editable: true, type: 'string' },
                    Password: { nullable: false, editable: true, type: 'password' },                                                                     
                    Fecha_Creacion: { nullable: false, editable: true, type: 'date'},
                    Telefono: { nullable: false, editable: true, type: 'string'},
                    Email: { nullable: false, editable: true, type: 'email' }                        
                }
            }
```

But when I create or update Usuarios, this exception happens:

> DateTime Fecha_Creacion = Convert.ToDateTime(data["Fecha_Creacion"].ToString());
>
> The string can not be recognized as a valid DateTime value

Columns

```
{
            field: 'Fecha_Creacion',
            title: 'Fecha de Creacion',
            width: 150,
            format: '{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'
            //template: '#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(DateOfBirth, "yyyy-MM-dd"), "MM/dd/yyyy") #'
```

THANKS,

Sorry for my English

Comment: Use DateTime.Parse and also, what's an example case of thr string for which it is generating an error?

Comment: send us the sample datetime which throws the error

Comment: Well obviously whatever string is given by `data["Fecha_Creacion"].ToString()` is not a valid DateTime. Since we can't see what value it holds we can't tell you why it's invalid.

Comment: You seem to be inserting raw json values into a database which is a big no-no, you must use a parameterized insert.

Comment: At grid it's '07/03/2018' in Fecha_Creacion field 2018-03-07 00:00:00.000 in database

Comment: So is that the 7th March or the 3rd July and how would the converter know?

Comment: 7th March, its just upside down at database, in column format : dd/MM/yyyy, In the controller should be format??

Comment: _You_ know that it's 7th March, how would the computer know? _Hint: Look at DateTime.ParseExact to replace Convert.ToDateTime_

Comment: DateTime Fecha_Creacion =DateTime.ParseExact(data["Fecha_Creacion"].ToString(),"{0:yyyy/MM/dd}",provider);                 Like this ok??   Incluiding CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

Comment: Stil the Exception, If I use ToISOSString(); in JS

Comment: Looks like you should rename `Ejecutar` to `SqlInjecutar`.